# Get Ref element from DOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I get the ref on the required element, that is, I have an array of certain nodes, but I need to get their refs and add an eventListener to them.

Now it looks like this

```
// Source: https://gist.github.com/xkomiks/afc0362432187b3d2b000dcd436fbe83
const nodes = elementsWithScrolls() // Array of DOM elements

nodes.forEach((node, index) => {
  node.addEventListener('scroll', someHandler, { passive: false });
});
```

I can add a listener not as a DOM element, but as a ref?

**UPDATE:**

**See examples:**
https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-haibt-5673v?file=/src/useDisableScroll.js

**The main question is how to get *ref* from a *node* element, is it possible?**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: We need to know a lot more about the setup in order to help you. What is `elementsWithScrolls`? How are those elements put in the DOM? (Via React? Some other way?) What issue(s) are you having with your current implementation? Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).